# Import-Module and Add-PSSnapin in PowerShell

Tags: powershell-3.0

How do I write a code that should check for Add-PSSnapin, if it does not exist then check for Import-Module, if that also does not exist then exit the script . I have written the below code but I get memory overflow issue while using it .

```
cls
Function GetModule {

$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

if(-not(Get-Module -Name VMware.VimAutomation.Core))
{
 Import-Module VMware.VimAutomation.Core
}

Elseif (-not(Get-PSSnapin -Name VMware.VimAutomation.Core))
{
   Add-PSSnapin VMware.VimAutomation.Core
}

Else {

Write-Host "VMware PowerCLI Modules are NOT INSTALLED on this machine !"
Exit
}   

}

GetModule
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple try/catch, along with the `-ErrorAction Stop` Parameter

```
Function GetModule {

Try {
Import-Module -Name VMware.VimAutomation.Core -ErrorAction Stop
}

catch {

    Write-Host "Unable to load VMware PowerCLI Module, trying the PSSnapin..."

    try {
    Add-PSSnapin VMware.VimAutomation.Core -ErrorAction Stop
    }

        catch {
        Write-Host "VMware PowerCLI Modules are NOT INSTALLED on this machine !"
        return
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you @Avshalom !
If I want to Exit the script if none of the 2 modules are found/installed on machine ? Then adding "EXIT" in the 2nd catch would solve the purpose ?

Comment: yes, but it will exit automatically anyway, you can add `return` at the end of the last catch block, updated my answer.